# AWS cli JMESpath query tag values

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, jmespath

As a follow-up to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66244870/object-construction-with-jmespath/66250454), I am having trouble getting tags to work right in this type of output.  I want to print a table with each property as a row.  This is how I expect it to look:

```
% aws --output table ec2 describe-instances --instance-id $id --query "Reservations[].Instances[0].[{ Property: 'Type', Value: InstanceType }]"         
-------------------------------
|      DescribeInstances      |
+-----------+-----------------+
| Property  |      Value      |
+-----------+-----------------+
|  Type     |  g4dn.12xlarge  |
+-----------+-----------------+
```

But with tag names it looks like this:

```
% aws --output table ec2 describe-instances --instance-id $id --query "Reservations[].Instances[0].[{ Property: 'Name', Value: Tags[?Key =='Name'].Value }]"   
-------------------
|DescribeInstances|
+-----------------+
|    Property     |
+-----------------+
|  Name           |
+-----------------+
||     Value     ||
|+---------------+|
||  Elliott-TKD  ||
|+---------------+|
```

The tag value is correct, but the formatting is weird, and when combined with more other rows the table gets really ugly.

Comment: Tags is an array, how do you expect it to render? Multiple rows, comma separated, else?

Comment: I'm filtering the array to get a a single string with `.Value`

Comment: Well, no, it will still be an array :)

Comment: Oh! Ok I see you're right.  So is there a way to turn it into a string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The filter part of your query (`[?Key == 'Name']`) is creating what JMESPath is describing as a [projection](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#projections).
You will have to reset this projection in order to extract a single string out of it.
Resetting a projection can be achieved using [pipes](https://jmespath.org/examples.html#pipes).

> Projections are an important concept in JMESPath. However, there are times when projection semantics are not what you want. A common scenario is when you want to operate of the result of a projection rather than projecting an expression onto each element in the array.
> For example, the expression `people[*].first` will give you an array containing the first names of everyone in the people array. What if you wanted the first element in that list? If you tried `people[*].first[0]` that you just evaluate `first[0]` for each element in the people array, and because indexing is not defined for strings, the final result would be an empty array, `[]`. To accomplish the desired result, you can use a pipe expression, `<expression> | <expression>`, to indicate that a projection must stop.

<sup>*Source: https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#pipe-expressions*</sup>

So your issue is very close to what they are describing here in the documentation and the reset of that projection can be achieved using:

```
Tags[?Key =='Name']|[0].Value
```

or, with:

```
Tags[?Key =='Name'].Value | [0]
```

which are two strictly identical queries.

Given the JSON:

```yaml
{
  "Reservations": [
    {
      "Instances": [
        {

          "Tags": [
            {
              "Key": "Name",
              "Value": "Elliott-TKD"
            },
            {
              "Key": "Foo",
              "Value": "Bar"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The query

```
Reservations[].Instances[0].[{ Property: `Name`, Value: Tags[?Key == `Name`]|[0].Value }]
```

Will give the expected

```json
[
  [
    {
      "Property": "Name",
      "Value": "Elliott-TKD"
    }
  ]
]
```

So it will render properly in your table

```
------------------------------
|      DescribeInstance      |
+------------+---------------+
|  Property  |     Value     |
+------------+---------------+
|    Name    |  Elliott-TKD  |
+------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Thank you!  I started out trying to write a very simple bash script, but now I'm starting to think it would have been easier to write it in Python with boto3.